# MySQL "an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to change a database entry with PHP but is stuck with this error message:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Bjelkholm Lövgren AND adress =
>   Brinellgatan 14 AND postnummer = 57135
>   ' at line 1

**Code:**

```
$namn = sanitize($_GET['namn']);
$adress = sanitize($_GET['adress']);
$postnummer = sanitize($_GET['postnummer']);
$postort = sanitize($_GET['postort']);
$email = sanitize($_GET['email']);
$status = 0;
$sql="UPDATE ordrar SET namn = $namn AND adress = $adress AND postnummer = $postnummer
AND postort = $postort AND email $email AND status = $status WHERE email = $email";
if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Thanks for answers.
/Victor

Comment: what does sanitize() function do?

Comment: Col. Shrapnel, cleans the variable from evil code.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no "evil code" to be cleaned. Perhaps this function does something unwanted and useless.

Comment: It is cleaning user input so there could be evil code.

Comment: there is no "evil code" for the database. No such code exists in the universe.

Comment: XSS and SQL-injection isn't evil code?

Comment: No injection possible if you follow syntax rules. Again: there is no evil code to eliminate. Just few syntax rules to follow.
And XSS has nothing to do with database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. SET statement values delimiter is comma, not AND
2. string values should be quoted

To make SET statements it would be nice to use a small function

```
function dbSet($fields) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

and than just

```
$table = "ordrar";
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$fields = explode(" ","namn adress postnummer postort email status");
$query  = "UPDATE $table SET ".dbSet($fields)." WHERE email='$email'";
```

will bring you properly formatted query

however, using email for row identification is bad.
I'd suggest to use an auto-increment id field to identify your records instead of email.

Answer (score 1):

quote your variables (i.e. adress = '$adress')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those values are strings, you should quote them in your query string, plus you are missing the equals sign when comparing the email.

```
$sql="UPDATE ordrar SET namn = '$namn' AND adress = '$adress' AND postnummer = '$postnummer'
AND postort = '$postort' AND email = '$email' AND status = '$status' WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

- Your strings need to be quoted (and escaped).
- You are missing an `=` for the email in the `SET` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you've got a bunch of syntax errors.  First, you'll need to properly quote your column names and values.  Column names get a grave (sideways quote) and values get a normal single quote.  And secondly you missed an equal sign before the $email variable.

Might I suggest breaking it up into multiple lines as well; this helps make it easier to debug.

```
$sql="UPDATE `ordrar` 
  SET `namn` = '$namn' AND 
  `adress` = '$adress' AND 
  `postnummer` = '$postnummer' AND 
  `postort` = '$postort' AND 
  `email` = '$email' AND 
  `status` = '$status' 
  WHERE `email` = '$email'";
```

One final suggestion, consider [binding your parameters using prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) as opposed to string interpolation.  They are more secure, and I personally find them easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

$namn = sanitize($_GET['namn']);

$adress = sanitize($_GET['adress']);

$postnummer = sanitize($_GET['postnummer']);

$postort = sanitize($_GET['postort']);

$email = sanitize($_GET['email']);

$status = 0;

$sql="UPDATE ordrar SET 
namn = '$namn' , 
adress = '$adress' , 
postnummer = '$postnummer' , 
postort = '$postort' , 
email = '$email' , 
status = '$status' 
WHERE email = '$email' ";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

Try this. Hope its work well ;-)